# If you lie down with dogs you will rise up with fleas

Tags: idiom-requests, proverb-requests

Though I have two questions, they are both related to this proverb, so I thought they could combined.

1. Are there other proverbs or idioms with the same effect?
2. Is there a proverb or an idiom that is the opposite? (Something like if you are with the good/honest/truthful, you will be one.)

Comment: Your first question seems like a list question, which isn't a good fit for the Q&A format. What specifically about the "lie down with dogs..." idiom doesn't match what you want to express? What difference in meaning do you want in the alternative sayings?

Comment: There's "one bad apple spoils the rest" that's related, but it doesn't imply making the choice to consort with a bad apple.

Answer (score 3):

Not the opposite, but covers both sides:

> ***“Tell me who your friends are, and I will tell you who you are.”***

---

Consider also [Proverbs 13:20](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Proverbs%2013%3A20&version=NKJV):

> He who walks with wise men will be wise,
>   But the companion of fools
>   will be destroyed.